# Particles don't go the way I want to?

Tags: math, bukkit, pi, trigonometry

Alrighty, so, I have this cool particle effect I created. But, it wouldn't spawn particles the way I want to or set entities on fire. Turns out, I teleport myself to see what the problem is, and - of course - it's not going the right direction at all!

So, I need some help with my math because I obviously went wrong somewhere. (And because of my theta being wrong, the task NEVER stops) Thanks in advance!

https://sendvid.com/pbgq02as

```
    public void run(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
          final Player player = e.getPlayer();
          final World w = player.getWorld();
          new BukkitRunnable(){
                  double t = Math.PI/4;
                  Location loc = player.getLocation();
                  public void run(){
                          t = t + 0.1*Math.PI;
                          for (double theta = 0; theta <= 2*Math.PI; theta = theta + Math.PI/32){
                                  double x = t*Math.cos(theta);
                                  double y = 2*Math.exp(-0.1*t) * Math.sin(t) + 1.5;
                                  double z = t*Math.sin(theta);
                                  loc.add(x,y,z);
                                  List<Entity> near = loc.getWorld().getEntities();
                                  w.playSound(loc, Sound.GHAST_FIREBALL, 1, 1);
                                  ParticleEffect.FLAME.display(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc, 1);
                                  for (Entity en : near) {
                                      if(en.getLocation().distance(loc) <= 1.0) {
                                          if (!en.equals(player)) {
                                              en.setFireTicks(20*5);
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                                  loc.subtract(x,y,z);

                                  theta = theta + Math.PI/64;

                                  x = t*Math.cos(theta);
                                  y = 2*Math.exp(-0.1*t) * Math.sin(t) + 1.5;
                                  z = t*Math.sin(theta);
                                  loc.add(x,y,z);
                                  ParticleEffect.FLAME.display(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, loc, 1);
                                  for (Entity en : near) {
                                      if(en.getLocation().distance(loc) <= 1.0) {
                                          if (!en.equals(player)) {
                                              en.setFireTicks(20*5);
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                                  loc.subtract(x,y,z);
                          }
                          if (t > 20){
                                  this.cancel();
                          }
                  }

          }.runTaskTimer(MagicBattle.getPlugin(), 0, 1);
    }
```

Interesting. I debugged my theta, and these are the values I get until the particles stop: http://pastebin.com/gSPnfus7

Comment: We don't know what you want your particles to do. Could you explain how you want them to operate, in general, and in relation to the player?

Comment: @Zymus Yeah, sorry. Should've explained that. What it should do is create a radial wave around the player that dampens and then depletes when theta is greater than 20. This is run when a player right clicks a book. What also must happen is if a player / entity is in radius of these particles, then they are set on fire. But, it doesn't spawn particles, it doesn't set players on fire, and the location travels into the air (see link).

Comment: I don't know what you're using to spawn the particles but it's usually done using packets or `world.playEffect(Location, Effect, int)` where `world` would be the player's world and `Effect` could be `Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES`. You could also try cloning the player's location (`loc.clone()`) each time you add the coordinates to it so that you don't have to then subtract the coordinates to not alter the original location. Is it just me or is part of your code duplicated?

Comment: @AdrianSohn I use the ParticleEffect lib by DarkBlade12. And yeah, it does look like my code is duplicated, but it is for a specific reason. Also, wouldn't loc.clone() just duplicate the location?

Comment: That makes it harder to help you since the problem might be with the library or the way you're using it. I tried out your code, with a few alterations, using my methods like described above and it worked nearly perfectly (what I saw was a sine/cosine wave, emanating in a circle from the player and then decreasing in magnitude over time).

Comment: @Adrian Sohn I trust you. I'll try what you suggested :)

Comment: @AdrianSohn Okay, I got rid of a duplicate code, I clone the location right after I add the location, I use Effect instead of ParticleEffect, and yet the flames fly above me and the task stops pretty quickly.

Comment: Without knowing exactly how you want the particles to move you'll have to play around with the different parameters yourself (make the task run longer, change multipliers and other constants). For example the flames start above you probably because you're adding 1.5 to the `y` coordinate. Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: @AdrianSohn For some reason, doing everything you suggested besides cloning the location helped. Works perfect now! Thanks!